# Outputting amount of prime numbers from a user input range

Tags: c++, loops

I'm in a Computer Science college class and have been tasked with writing a program to output the amount of prime numbers within a range indicated by the user. Here's the prompt:

> Write a C++ program to ask the user and input a beginning value and an
>   ending value for a range of integers. Count and output the number of
>   prime numbers in this range (inclusive of endpoints). For instance, if
>   the user enters 2 and 10, the out put should be: "There are 4 prime
>   number in the given range." Do not output the prime numbers themselves
>   in the final submission. Do NOT use a break statement in your code.
>
> Copy and paste the output at the bottom of the code as a comment.
>   Write your name to the output. No other function than main() is
>   necessary.
>
> Test data: 50 to 100.

I've searched around for potential solutions online but still can't wrap my head around how to write this program with the restrictions. Here's the restrictions:

- I cannot use a break statement
- I cannot use a function

My class's latest concept is loops (for, while, etc...) so I cannot use arrays or anything of that sort.

I've modified a code online to fit the prompt but it uses break:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int min, max, i, primeNumbers;

    cout << "Enter a minimum integer: " ;
    cin >> min;
    cout << "Enter a maximum integer: " ;
    cin >> max;

    primeNumbers = 0;
    for (i=min; i <= max; i++) 
        for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) 
                break;
            else if (i == j+1){
                primeNumbers++;
            }

        }   

    cout << "There are " << primeNumbers << " prime numbers" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a minimum integer: 50
Enter a maximum integer: 100
There are 10 prime numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to keep track of whether any factors were found.

```
for (i=min; i <= max; i++)
{
    bool hasFactor = false;

    for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) 
            hasFactor = true;

        if (i == j+1 && !hasFactor)
            primeNumbers++;
    }
}
```

You could then move the second `if` outside of the inner loop.

```
for (i=min; i <= max; i++)
{
    bool hasFactor = false;

    for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) 
            hasFactor = true;
    }

    if (!hasFactor)
        primeNumbers++;
}
```

You could also optimize it by stopping the inner loop as soon as `hasFactor` is set, simulating a `break` statement without actually using one.

```
for (i=min; i <= max; i++)
{
    bool hasFactor = false;

    for (int j=2; j<i && !hasFactor; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) 
            hasFactor = true;
    }

    if (!hasFactor)
        primeNumbers++;
}
```